# d3-network click event - how to receive clicked node definition?

Tags: vue.js, onclick

I've been working with a [d3-network Vue component](https://github.com/emiliorizzo/vue-d3-network) and I want to display the name of node when it is clicked. Here is the usage of this component:

```html
<d3-network :net-nodes="nodes" :net-links="links" :options="options" @node-click="testFunc()" />
```

And here are the `nodes` and `links` arrays.

```js
      nodes: [
        { id: 1, name: "Node 1", _color: "#aa00bb" },
        { id: 2, name: "Node 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "Node 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "Node 4" },
        { id: 5, name: "Node 5" },
        { id: 6, name: "Node 6" },
        { id: 7, name: "Node 7" },
        { id: 8, name: "Node 8" },
        { id: 9, name: "Node 9" },
      ],
      links: [
        { sid: 1, tid: 2 },
        { sid: 2, tid: 8 },
        { sid: 3, tid: 4 },
        { sid: 4, tid: 5 },
        { sid: 5, tid: 6 },
        { sid: 7, tid: 8 },
        { sid: 5, tid: 8 },
        { sid: 3, tid: 8 },
        { sid: 7, tid: 9 },
      ],
```

The component looks like this;

[image]

The `@node-click="testFunc()"` is fired when a node is clicked. What I want to do is displaying the names of each node element when they are clicked. How do I do that? It doesn't matter if it's displayed on console on alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their docs: https://github.com/emiliorizzo/vue-d3-network

node-click: fired when click on node, emits (event,node-object)

Which means you will receive the "event" object as first argument and the actual "node" object as the second.

```
testFunc(event, node) {
  console.log(node)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs](https://github.com/emiliorizzo/vue-d3-network#events)!

The `node-click` receives two arguments - `event` and `node-object`

```html
 <d3-network :net-nodes="nodes" :net-links="links" :options="options" @node-click="onClick" />
```

... in script section:

```js
  methods: {
    onClick(event, node) {
      console.log(event)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(node))
    }
  }
```

Comment: I read the doc but it seems I missed this part. Thanks for the help.